# recyclerview is not scrolling above the keypad for new messages

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
    messagesAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(messagesList);

    userMessageList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list_users);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    userMessageList.setHasFixedSize(true);

     userMessageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

      userMessageList.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);
```

This is my code to set the recyclerview and adapter for message

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your activity in `manifest.xml`

```
<activity
       android:name="YourActivity"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

**Update**

You will scroll to top when you insert new message

```
rv.scrollToPosition(0)
```

Comment: this is my RecyclerView code :- <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messages_list_users"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/chat_bar_layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

Comment: Post your layout xml which contains recyclerview

Comment: How do you insert new message in adapter?

Comment: using push key();

Comment: In Android there is not automated system that know you have inserted item, and it should scroll.

Comment: I did not get you. Can you be specific?

Comment: See, I am telling you way. Code is yours. Think & debug what's happening. Logic is that when you insert a new message, then just scroll recycler view to top. So the recent message be visible.

Comment: If you need then also add keyboard open/close listener

Comment: thank's but i can solve my problem with smoothScrollToPosition

Comment: scrollToPosition & smoothScrollToPosition are same thing in base dude. Just animation difference. by the way congrats